# Remove Google widget

Tags: google, app-widgets, home-screen

How do I remove the chunky, waste-of-space Google search widget at the top of every home screen? And if I do, can I put apps there instead? I know I can add and remove Google widgets on the main home screen: [image]
Note: I am not willing to root it.

Comment: The easiest way is to just disable 'Google App' (the latest name for 'Google Search') from your app settings. You may have to, additionally, uninstall updates in order for the disable button to appear.

Comment: @bmdixon This is not a Nexus.

Comment: @NonnyMoose For starters, you haven't said what device you're using so I had no way of knowing. Secondly, the answers in that question aren't specific to Nexus (despite the linked question including that information).

Comment: @bmdixon Sorry, I confused this question with one in which I _did_ give that information.